# What does the demon kali staying in gold mean?

Tags: mahabharata

Near the beginning of the kali yuga, Parikshit maharaja allowed the demon kali to stay in gold amongst other places. What are the consequences of this?

1) Does this mean we should not own any gold or wear gold jewellery?

2) What about gold coloured items which are not really made of gold but only painted in a gold colour? Can one own/use such items?

Comment: Kali was allowed to stay in 4 places by prakshit 1. prostitute 2.dopple ganngers(alcholic) 3. gamblers 4. those hide property (black money, user gold for wrong means) like wearing gold or gold like ornaments in legs, in toilet seat (kali is said to reside with people who misuse the money.

Comment: Regarding question 1: if you satisfy certain requirements the effects of Kali are nullified. As for your second question nothing is wrong with having fake gold since Kali doea not reside in there.

Comment: gold means money. In those days, there was no concept of cash, so gold was used for all transactions. and what he means is Kali stays where there is Lot of desire for money and huge transactions involved. you can see this in corruption, greedy politicians & businessmen stashing away crores of rupees, black money, bribe etc.

Comment: @ram you did not answer his question.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu, if gold does not mean actual gold, but money, the question itself becomes moot. gold jewelry has anti-bacterial properties, it is also used as a 'pavitra', gold on certain fingers, nose, ears helps nerves. so it is recommended. just don't be greedy is the message behind kali in gold.

Comment: I have added an answer but deleted by moderator asking for sources, how can i provide sources for my understanding of scripture? As per their expectation, I have to write a book on stackexchange questions and then cite that as a source?

Comment: https://rockmine.blogspot.com/2023/10/stackexchange-what-does-demon-kali.html Here are my thoughts on this